# caml query that searches for specific records

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml

hello everyone form this query to find column records until this moment works for me but when I want to add that look for other records of the column department gives error
I would appreciate your help

Query Good

```
"<View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Usuario'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</Value></Eq>" + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Puesto'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query></View>"
```

Query Bad

```
"< View >< Query ><Where><Or><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Usuario' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text +  "</ Value ></ Eq >" +  "< Eq >< FieldRef Name = 'Puesto' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value ></ Eq >" + "< Eq > < FieldRef Name = 'Departamento' /> < Value Type = 'Text' >" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value > </ Eq ></ Or ></ Or ></And></ Where ></Query></View>";
```

Comment: Entonces la referencia por este es 'Departamento', verdad? Pero es el tipo "text" tambien o un otra cosa? Si no es mismo... es posible este es la problema.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code the query is not well formated. The above query can be written as below

```
"< View >< Query ><Where><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Usuario' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text +  "</ Value ></ Eq >" +  "< Eq >< FieldRef Name = 'Puesto' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value ></ Eq ></And>" + "< Eq > < FieldRef Name = 'Departamento' /> < Value Type = 'Text' >" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value > </ Eq ></ Or></ Where ></Query></View>"
```

or if you want query to be as the above correct one with additional **AND condition** so refer below query

```
"< View >< Query ><Where><And><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Usuario' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text +  "</ Value ></ Eq >" +  "< Eq >< FieldRef Name = 'Puesto' />< Value Type = 'Text' >" +Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value ></ Eq ></ Or>" + "< Eq > < FieldRef Name = 'Departamento' /> < Value Type = 'Text' >" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</ Value > </ Eq ></And></ Where ></Query></View>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usuario=Txt_Buscar.Text **or** Puesto=Txt_Buscar.Text **or** Departamento=Txt_Buscar.Text:

```
"<View><Query><Where>
<Or>
    <Or>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Usuario' /><Value Type = 'Text'>" +Txt_Buscar.Text +  "</Value></Eq>" +  
        "<Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Puesto' /><Value Type = 'Text'>" +Txt_Buscar.Text + "</Value></Eq>
    </Or>" + 
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Departamento' /><Value Type = 'Text'>" + Txt_Buscar.Text + "</Value></Eq>
</Or>
</Where></Query></View>"
```

[Query schema in CAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the queries that you recommended me and gives this error

[image]